# Generating id's and pushing them into an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function generating color id's:

```js
const hexaColor = () => {
  let str = '0123456789abcdef'
  let color = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length)
    color += str[index]
  }
  return '#' + color
}
```

And then I'm using another function, as I want to have an array of six generated colors:

```js
const colorArray= ()=> {  
    let colors =  []
    for (let i=0; i>=6; i++ ){
        colors.push(hexaColor[i])
        console.log(colors)
    }
    return colors;   
    
    }
console.log(colorArray())
```

however, what I see in a console is just an empty array. What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "color id" - your code is actually generating 24-bit RGB colors in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: Your code defines `hexaColor` as a function, but your `colorArray` function uses `hexaColor` as though it were an array (note the `[i]` indexer).

Comment: You are not calling the `hexaColor` correctly: `hexaColor[i]` instead of `hexaColor()`, try this

Comment: ok so how should be written?

Comment: @Paul-Louis Mas tried that too, returns the function expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a code error

The loop did not run at all

The condition will never be met`i>=6`

Change the condition at the top of the loop

```
    for (let i=0; i>=6; i++ ){
```

This is how it works

```
    for (let i=0; i<=6; i++ ){
```

also this line fix to

```
colors.push(hexaColor()[i])
```

Comment: corrected it, does not work either

Comment: @Al_Milligan
see my answer updated

Comment: thanks man, it is better now; however it returns array like this  ["#", "6", "3", "9", "f", "0", "9"] I'll figure out how to amend.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in your loop you said when `i >= 6`, but it's `i <=6` because `i` starts from `0`.

```js
const hexaColor = () => {
  let str = '0123456789abcdef'
  let color = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length)
    color += str[index]
  }
  return '#' + color;
}

const colorArray = ()=> {  
    let colors =  []
    for (let i=0; i<=6; i++ ){
        colors.push(hexaColor());
    }
    return colors;   
    
    }
console.log(colorArray())
```

Comment: it doesn't work either way I'm afraid

Comment: But the resulted array is what you're searching for no?
Because you're just maybe not using it correctly, can you show where do you use colorsArray?

Comment: so far I just call after the expression, later I want to use it is a react component

Comment: Can you edit your post and put the code that is using it to identify the issue?

Comment: I dont have credentials yet